# Precise relationship between two proofs of the Hurwitz theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected smooth projective algebraic curves over an algebraically closed field $k$, $f: X \to Y$ a finite morphism, $g_X$ the genus of $X$. What is the precise relationship between the two known proofs of the Hurwitz theorem relating $g_X$ and $g_Y$ - which are the topological one for $k = \mathbb{C}$ and one that works for any $k$? In what moral sense are they the same, and in what moral sense are they different?

It is maybe worth remarking that if $k$ has finite characteristic we should require the differential of $f$ to be nonzero at some point of $X$ (if $df$ equals zero identically the Hurwitz formula makes no sense).

Comment: What are the ''two known proofs" you are talking about?

Comment: I presume one is using a triangulation on Y and pulling back to X and computing the Euler characteristic using these triangulations. The other one must be the proof using the exact sequence of differential forms.

Comment: I suggest, if you are not familiar with it, perhaps looking at a proof of the Poincare Hopf theorem relating triangulations at least to vector fields, e.g. Theorem 30 chapter 11, of Spivak's Diff Geom vol. 1.